# How do I pass input a variable DIM into my ms access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm attempting to input a variable declared as a string into my access database. When the button is clicked "Ticket Status" is not entered into the access database.

```vb
    Dim str As String
    str = "update [tblUsers] set [Campus] = '" & cmboxCampus.SelectedItem & "' , [ProblemType] = '" & cmboxProblemType.SelectedItem & "', [IfOther] = '" & txtIfOther.Text & "', [Status] = '" & TicketStatus & "', [ProblemDescription] = '" & txtDescription.Text & "'  Where [Username] = '" & txtUsername.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    TicketStatus = "Ticket being Assigned"

    If txtIfOther.ReadOnly = True And txtIfOther.Text <> "" Then
        MsgBox("When selecting 'other' please specify")
    End If

    If txtDescription.Text = "" Or cmboxCampus.SelectedItem = "" Or cmboxProblemType.SelectedItem = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill out all fields.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        MsgBox("Your ticket has been successfully submitted.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Never concat values into a query string.  use SQL Parameters which will result in easier to read code, fewer type conversions and fewer syntax errors due to certain kinds of text.  Read [ask] and take the [tour], then hover over those tag selections and remove those that do not/cannot apply.  Read your code out loud - you are setting the status after you built that horrible SQL...and even after you have fed the SQL to the DB Command object.  You should also check the data *before* you embark on the DB ops